# Make own loadhelper function (like in CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying make every day something new. Now i want to make function to dynamic load helper without include and creating new class object

In code igniter that's look like 

`$this->load->helper('syslog_helper');`

and now we can use 

`syslog_helper->some_function()`

file is automatic including, object is automatic created and we can use them

Question is: how can I do the same think using pure PHP ?

Comment: Create a class name load that has a method named helper, if you want it accessible with `$syslog_helper` then load needs to be able to call the original class so when you create an instance pass the `$this` as part of it's constructor.  Then the main class should use the magic `__set` method etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

> Create a class name load that has a method named helper, if you want it accessible with $syslog_helper then load needs to be able to call the original class so when you create an instance pass the $this as part of its constructor. Then the main class should use the magic __set method etc

Helper class to load:

```
class syslog_helper{

}
```

Loader class:

```
class loader{
    protected $obj;
    public function __construct($obj){
        //save the controller instance as a property
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

   public function helper($class){
        //require the class file - don't need to in this case as they are all in the same file for sandbox
        //require_once HELPER_DIR.$class.'.php';

        //create a new instance of Helper and assign it back to the controller
        $this->obj->$class = new $class;
    }

}
```

Base controller class

```
class foo{

    public $data = [];
    public $load;

    public function __construct(){
        //create the loader instance, pass an instance of the controller (this)
        $this->load = new loader($this);
    }

    public function bar(){
        //call the loader's helper() method with the name of the helper class
        $this->load->helper('syslog_helper');

        print_r($this->syslog_helper);
    }


    public function __set($key, $value){
        //create a dynamic property
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key){
       //get a dynamic property
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

}
```

Call it:

```
(new foo)->bar();
```

Output:

```
syslog_helper Object
(
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b954930392d7e29e3b75b92db33cbc0d39f3d0f7)

As you can see above, `$this->syslog_helper` gets populated with our helper class just like CI does it.

So it flows in this order:

1. **$foo = new foo** - create instance of controller, assign the loader class (with a back reference to the controller) `$this->load = new loader($this);`
2. **$foo->bar()** - call `bar()` this would be the request function in the controller, such as what the URL routes to.
3. **$foo->load->helper('syslog_helper')** - use the `load` property (instance of loader) to call its helper method, passing the name of the helper class as a string. Helper method should require the class file, and then create an instance of that class.  `new $class`
4. **$this->obj->$class = new $class;**  - then that instance is assigned to a dynamic property named the same as what was passed in
5. **$this->obj->$class** - Controller's __set magic method is triggered, storing instance of helper in `Controler->data[$helper]`
6. **$foo->syslog_helper()** - Controller's __get magic method is triggered returning `Controler->data[$helper]` or the instance of the helper we just created.

I just made this up, but I am sure CI is similar.  You could look in the parent class of the Controllers etc.. and see how they do it.

Hope that makes sense...

**One simple improvement** you could make for the above code

I think CI does this, is to allow aliasing of the property... like this:

```
class loader{
    protected $obj;
    public function __construct($obj){
        //save the controller instance as a property
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

   public function helper($class, $alias = null){
        //if no alias default to the class name
        if(!$alias) $alias = $class;

        //require the class file - don't need to in this case as they are all in the same file for sandbox
        //require_once APPPATH.'helpers/'.$class.'.php';

        //create a new instance of Helper and assign it back to the controller
        $this->obj->$alias = new $class;
    }

}
```

Now if we did this in the controller's bar method:

```
class foo{

    public function bar(){
       //call the loader's helper() method with the name of the helper class
       $this->load->helper('syslog_helper');
       print_r($this->syslog_helper);

       $this->load->helper('syslog_helper', 'syslog_helper_2');
       print_r($this->syslog_helper_2);
   }
```

Output:

```
syslog_helper Object
(
)

syslog_helper Object
(
)
```

You now have 2 instances of the helper, one named `syslog_helper` and the other `syslog_helper_2`. If we didn't alias them, the second call would simply overwrite the property in the controller leaving us with just one instance.

So you can see above we added a whole lot of flexibility with essentially 1 line of code.  Big improvements don't have to be complex.

[Sandboxy](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd8b500215b0373662a6b30c8342c5b39c2eefb3)

Obviously you should flesh this out a bit more. By adding more things, like error checking for classes (files) that don't exist, `__unset` and `__isset` magic methods etc... But, this is the basic functionality you wanted.

Similarly you can add, `model` and `library` methods with the only real difference being the location.  For that I would probably go with the magic `__call` method instead of 3 functions that do the same.

**Implement  load->model, load->library and load->helper**

```
class loader{
    protected $obj;
    public function __construct($obj){
        //save the controller instance as a property
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }


public function __call($method, $args){
    //type => folder
    $allowed = ['helper'=>'helpers','model'=>'models', 'library'=>'libraries'];

    if(!isset($allowed[$method])) throw new Exception('Unknown method '.$method);

    if(!isset($args[0])) throw new Exception('Missing required argument for method '.$method);

        $class = $args[0];
        $alias = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : $class;

         //require the class file - don't need to in this case as they are all in the same file for sandbox
         //require_once APPPATH.$allowed[$method].'/'.$class.'.php';

        //create a new instance of Helper and assign it back to the controller
        $this->obj->$alias = new $class;
   }

}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da795747241a7485ce285b0a1334a1bdc9aaea65)

**Implement singletons**

A singleton is basically re-using the same instance of the class for future calls, you can implement this with a few more changes to loader:

```
class syslog_helper{
    public $test;
}

class loader{
    protected $obj;
    protected static $instances = [];


    public function __construct($obj){
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){
        //type => folder
        $allowed = ['helper'=>'helpers','model'=>'models', 'library'=>'libraries'];

        if(!isset($allowed[$method])) throw new Exception('Unknown method '.$method);

        if(!isset($args[0])) throw new Exception('Missing required argument for method '.$method);

        $class = $args[0];
        $alias = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : $class;

        //if this is the first time we instantiated [$method][$alias] save it
        if(!isset(static::$instances[$method][$alias])){

             //require the class file - don't need to in this case as they are all in the same file for sandbox
             //require_once APPPATH.$allowed[$method].'/'.$class.'.php';

             //create a new instance of Helper and assign it back to the controller
            static::$instances[$method][$alias] = new $class;
        }

        //return the saved static instance
        $this->obj->$alias = static::$instances[$method][$alias];
    }       
}

class foo{

    public $data = [];
    public $load;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load = new loader($this);
    }

    public function bar(){
       $this->load->helper('syslog_helper');

       print_r('bar::Test before: '.$this->syslog_helper->test."\n");
       $this->syslog_helper->test = 'test';
       print_r('bar:Test after: '.$this->syslog_helper->test."\n");
    }

    public function biz(){
       $this->load->helper('syslog_helper');
       print_r('biz:Test: '.$this->syslog_helper->test."\n");
    }


    public function __set($key, $value){
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key){
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

}

$foo = new foo;
$foo->bar();
$foo->biz();
```

Output:

```
bar::Test before: 
bar:Test after: test
biz:Test: test
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e70ed19416647a84ba9c0c0784fa714b1f42f70)

The important thing here is that, when we call `$this->load->helper('syslog_helper');` from `biz()` in the controller we are getting the same instance of the helper we created previously.  You can tell this because the public property I added to the helper retains it's value we set in `bar()`.  You could actually call this anywhere in your code and get the same instance with the same data stored in it, it was just easier (shorter) for examples sake to do it this way.

This is useful if you need the same helper in multiple classes, instead of creating multiple instances you can re-use them.  I am not sure if CI does this right off the top of my head... lol

In this case I think it's acceptable to do them as a singleton, if you need a new copy you can just alias it and then that would be a independent instance.

One last thing I should add, is that CI probably doesn't pass the controller instance to the loader class.  This is because CI calls the controller from the routing so it already has the instance of the Controller at it's disposal.  And as CI is a singleton it can probably be accessed with `$CI = get_instance();` inside of loader, so there is no need to pass it along in the the way I showed inside of the CI framework.  Basically they just access the same data in a different way.

Cheers!

Comment: Sure, I do PHP for almost 10 years.  It's easy for me.  Glad I could help.  Personally I am not a fan of how CI loads its class, I would rather use an auto loader (PSR4) such as this one I wrote:  [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Autoloader)  This is similar to how Composer does it, if your familiar with that.  Basically it makes your code more re-usable outside of the framework, more portable.

Comment: That said, it's a good example of how to use magic methods.  Another issue with this is that it tends to break advanced IDE's (such as Eclipse PDT) ability to do autocomplete.  However CI may save and re-use the instance from loader.  For example you could save the helper instance in a static variable inside of loader then re-use that instance for other load calls.  I can show you an example of that if you want.

There are always trade offs, goods and bads.  Just depends on what you want.